ZonedDateTime in MyBatis
I have a java ZonedDateTime which I am trying to insert into a MySQL Date column (the DBA refuses to change the type - the date should have a time component since it is an audit date/time for when an event occurs - I would like to have the java code retain the time in case someday the DBA changes their mind).
When MyBatis tries to insert the ZonedDateTime into the Date column, I receive the following error:
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr\x00\x0Djava.time.Ser\x95]\x84\xBA\x1B''H\xB2\x)C\x00\....' for column auditDate at row 1

What would be the best way to get MyBatis to insert the ZonedDateTime into the MySQL Date column? Do I need to cast to a java.util.Date or some other type to successfully perform the insertion?

afaik there's no official support for ZonedDateTime in the SQL standard. Some driver/RDBMS combos might permit it - though I'm not sure what they do with it when they do. 'Officially' only LocalDateTime and OffsetDateTime are supported. You could use the latter and then store the TZ separately

You are inserting a value into a DATE column via JDBC. Connector/J maps the DATE data type to java.sql.Date class. So you need to convert ZonedDateTime to java.sql.Date. By the way, what exactly do you mean by: have the java code retain the time ?

@Abra No longer true about java.sql.Date. In JDBC 4.2 and later, all JDBC drivers are required to support java.time types. The terribly flawed legacy class java.sql.Date is replaced by java.time.LocalDate.

@Abra this is incorrect. java.sql.Date is in fact completely obsolete and should never be used for anything. For backwards compatibility reasons, rs.getDate() continues to return it, ps.setDate() continues to support it, and rs.getObject(colId) will also return it.. but don't use those. Use .ps.setObject(someInstanceOfOffsetDateTime), and use rs.getObject(colId, OffsetDateTime.class). As per JDBC5 spec, all JDBC drivers must support it. And it avoids the pain. Because java.sql.Date lies and breaks if tzdata changes, and that changes all the time!

Do I need to cast to a java.util.Date ... Definitely not. Both java.util.Date and java.sql.Date are long outdated and were filled with design problems, so don’t use any of them. Convert your ZonedDateTime to a LocalDate as shown in the answer. Also take into account in which time zone you want to consider the date if it’s not necessarily the same as the time zone of your ZonedDateTime.

@rzwitserloot would you be kind enough to link to that "JDBC5 spec" - these things are devilishly difficult to find?

@g00se I meant 4.2, apologies. Here's the PDF of JDBC 4.2 from oracle for some reason (not openjdk.org) - you can search the PDF for OffsetDateTime.

Ah thanks yes. I'm slightly disappointed it's not 5 ;)

@g00se  The JDBC 4.x specification is defined in the Java Community Process (JCP). See JSR 221: JDBC™ 4.0 API Specification. You’ll find links there for the JDBC 4.2 and 4.3 specs.

Thanks Basil but I see no 4.3 link there. And actually not even a 4.2 one

@g00se Click through the Download page links for "Maintenance Release 3" & "Maintenance Release 2". That is how the JSRs work.

@BasilBourque so you're saying that the Connector/J documentation is incorrect, yes?

@Abra Yes. Well, no, not incorrect, but that doc is out of date. By a decade. JDBC 4.2 arrived as part of Java 8 in 2014. I would file a doc-bug issue, but I am not a MySQL user.

tl;dr
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , myZonedDateTime.toLocalDate() ) ;

Details
As commented, the ZonedDateTime class is not mapped in JDBC.
The JDBC 4.x specification is defined in the Java Community Process (JCP). See JSR 221: JDBC™ 4.0 API Specification. You’ll find links there for the JDBC 4.2 and 4.3 specs.
The reason for the lack of support for ZonedDateTime is that the SQL standard recognizes only offset-from-UTC, not time zones. The SQL standard type TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE is a misnomer. The authors actually meant offset, as they were not savvy with date-time handling.
See a similar Answer I recently posted. It offers more detail.
The DATE type in MySQL represents a date only, no time of day, no offset, no time zone. So you could store the date portion of your ZonedDateTime.
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;

To record a moment, a specific point on the timeline, use the SQL standard type TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE. In MySQL, the matching type is TIMESTAMP.

Do I need to cast to a java.util.Date

Never use the terribly flawed legacy date-time classes. These were entirely supplanted by the modern java.time classes.

I think Instant works pretty well, at least with recent connectors. The funny thing about all this is that, when it's used, MySql seems to be just storing the ascii string ;)

@g00se Instant may be supported by a particular JDBC driver. But support for Instant is not required by the JDBC spec. So  code using Instant will not be portable across other drivers and other databases.

That's true. I was just saying it happens to work

Also, Instant is about as close as it gets to java.sql.Timestamp of course

@g00se The JDBC spec really should support Instant, as it would be so convenient for calling programmers. The code would be utterly simple for any driver: OffsetDateTime#toInstant and Instant#atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ).

I'm hopeful for the next iteration of the spec
